# why the difference in node_modules when npm install is run multiple times?

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules, package.json

I have a package.json file which has dependencies defined as below (i.e im using  exact versions for every package):

```
 "dependencies": {
        "async": "0.9.2",
        "body-parser": "1.15.1",
        "cookie-parser": "1.4.2",
        "csvtojson": "0.3.21",
        "express": "4.13.4",
        "jsonwebtoken": "7.1.9",
        "lodash": "4.16.6",
        "mongodb": "1.4.40",
        "request": "2.78.0",
        "seneca": "3.3.0",
        "seneca-amqp-transport": "2.1.0"
    }
```

When i run npm install on this package.json file twice and compare the node_modules folders generated, i see differences in the folder. The difference is usually in the readme,_from and url field of the packages (Refer attachments for the same).

[image: readme difference]

[image: url difference]

[image: from difference]

1. Is this expected?
2. Does this difference have any impact on my application ?
3. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use .gitignore (Or something like it) to ignore the node_module. There is no need to push them so you don't have to worry about this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Eric - node_modules folder is in my gitignore file already. The reason behind posting this question is that , when we do deployments on server, npm install is run. some of the features do not work as expected. we copy the npm packages from previous deployment (backup) to fix it.  This is adhoc , sometimes fresh deployments work smoothly and sometimes copying backup modules is required. This slows down our deployment process and required manual intervention when issue occurs. Im trying to get to the root of it.